# spark2-submit different from spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

How is spark2-submit different from spark submit. I need to migrate my code from `spark 1.6 to spark 2.4` Can I still use spark-submit to launch my application or is it compulsory to move to spark2-submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Cloudera Hadoop. Spark 2.x versions had major changes compared to 1.x versions. In a way, there are compatibility issues. So when your existing production jobs that used 1.x version runs on 2.x, there are more chances that your job may fail.

Just to provide backward compatibility, Cloudera added "spark2-submit" and asked the users to use it for all "go-forward" jobs. And "spark-submit" would still use 1.x version and you need not touch any of the production jobs.

So it is just for the compatibility reasons.

Comment: what other code change will be required for transition to 2.x?

Comment: no code change is required.. just make sure 1.x jobs use spark-submit and 2.x jobs uses spark2-submit.

Comment: hope it helped you...pls consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark-submit for Spark 2.X after setting following environment variables:

1) SPARK_HOME to path of spark2-client (e.g. /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client)
2) SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2

Using these two configuration, even if you have both Spark 1.x and Spark 2.x installed on Cluster, you can run jobs using Spark 2.x by same commands like spark-shell, spark-submit